# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx controller doesn't keep `path` if service responses with new relative url `Location` header

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, spring-security-oauth2, nginx-ingress

TL;DR Kubernetes Ingress Nginx controller doesn't keep `path` if underlying service redirects to a relative URL

I have the following Ingress configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: release-name-test-tool
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "kub.internal.company.com"
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /api/test-tool(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: test-tool-service
              port:
                name: http
```

Behind `test-tool-service` is a Spring Boot Application with authorization by OAuth2 protocol.
As a first step, the application redirects to `http://server:port/oauth2/authorization/test-tool`.

But in the K8S deployment, `path` part is missed in response's `location` header  and I receive `404` after redirection (because there is no Ingress rule for `kub.internal.company.com/oauth2(/|$)(.*)`)

*Actual*:

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 11 Aug 2021 13:04:24 GMT
expires: 0
location: https://kub.internal.company.com/oauth2/authorization/test-tool
pragma: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

*Expected*:

```
location: https://kub.internal.company.com/api/test-tool/oauth2/authorization/test-tool
```

So, `location` header in response doesn't contain `path` from the Ingress configuration.

The same service deployed on bare metal + Nginx `proxy_pass` configuration works fine.

PS: I found a similar issue in GitHub https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5076 but without an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found two steps solution that works for me:

- Application side. Spring Boot has a configuration for [Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.webserver.use-behind-a-proxy-server). We need to set processing of **X-Forwarded-*** headers to `FRAMEWORK`(default is `NONE`). Spring Boot will automatically update the `Location` header based on the header value:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK
```

- Nginx side. In my K8S setup, not all required **X-Forwarded-*** headers were set. In my case `X-Forwarded-Prefix` was not configured. Luckily there is a Nginx-Ingress configuration for that - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#x-forwarded-prefix-header :

```
ingress: 
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: /api/test-tool
```

How everything works together:

- Request `/api/test-tool/hello` is proxied to `/hello`. Nginx also set `X-Forwarded-Prefix : /api/test-tool`
- Spring Boot application handles request for `/name` and made a redirection using `Location` header: `Location : /oauth2/authorization/test-tool`
- Since we set up processing of `X-Forwarded-Prefix` Spring Boot adds proxy path to `Location` : `Location : /api/test-tool/oauth2/authorization/test-tool`
- Response is proxied back to the client's browser and we achieve what we want, the browser is redirected to a correct authorization server.